# Java Array Search, on a value which i'snt inside the array Exception Error

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist, crash-reports

I have a program where a user enters in a year and it searches an array with years inside of it.

When a user enters a 'invalid' year the program crashes, how can i over come this? Will i need to use a try and catch statement?

Comment: yes use try-catch as this is a custom error condition not in built

Comment: Is this dupposed to be a joke ? If nit I think the problem is in the `if` condition on line 42.

Comment: Show us your code or we are unable to help you.

Comment: @Abu Thanks just double checking!

Comment: @SiyuSong Song i didnt want to put code on here since i want to learn myself! thanks anwyay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, if you were trying to 'catch' an `InvalidYearException`, you would do something like this:

```
try {
    //  Your code (the code that will possibly cause an exception to be thrown)
} catch(InvalidYearException exception) {
    //  Your code (the code that will be executed when you 'catch' an InvalidYearException)
    //  for example:
    System.out.println("Error!" + exception.getMessage());
}
```